# Should this tag be put into [storage]? Or not?

Tags: discussion, tags

**This is a discussion, it is NOT an invitation to start burninating this tag. We must follow [the documented procedure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/1081494) here.**

We have a tag, [storage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/storage). I don't think it is a good tag, though. At the same time, it does not meet the criteria to be eligible for burnination:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Well... it does describe the questions. And it specific to some extent. But... there are other tags that are almost always *better*. It isn't *not descriptive*, it is just unhelpful because it is vague IMO.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes, the storage is on-topic here (assuming it is about Ubuntu, anyways).

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Yes, it is somehow about storage. But again, a more specific tag would likely be more useful.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, it does not.

---

IMO, this tag should not be used and the following should be used instead:

- [filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/filesystem)
- [files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/files)/[directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/directory)
- [hard-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive)/[disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/disk)
- [partitioning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/partitioning)
- [ext4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ext4)/[zfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zfs)/[ntfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ntfs)/[btrfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/btrfs)/etc.
- etc.

---

But, what should we do with this tag? It failed the burnination criteria, but at the same time, I feel it can almost always be replaced with a more specific tag.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that it's a bad tag. Being generic is not necessarily a bad thing and not  enough reason to remove it. The fact that there are other tags that may be more specific is also not a good reason to have the [storage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/storage) tag removed.

Generic tags are useful to people that have interest in the general subject and specific tags can be used alongside the generic ones to narrow down the scope of the question.

So I'm not in favor of removing the [storage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/storage) tag.